# Remix V2 useLoaderData issue while running in dev mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, remix.run

In a basic Remix V2 app, i need help understanding if the following is expected behavior, a bug in V2, or possibly a missing configuration option or setting.

**When running in development mode via `npm run dev` i am seeing the `useLoaderData` hook receive a JavaScript object declaration as its value as opposed to JSON.**

I could not find anything related to this issue in the Remix documentation.

**Full details to reproduce the issue:**

I created an demo Remix V2 app by running `npm create-remix@latest`

I wrote a simulated API backend method stored in `app/api/notes.ts` which has one method that returns JSON data that it loads from a JSON file that i have stored at the root of my application `./app/notes.json`:

```
import fs from 'fs/promises';
...
export async function getStoredNotes() {
  const rawFileContent = await fs.readFile('notes.json', { encoding: 'utf-8' });
  const data = JSON.parse(rawFileContent);
  const storedNotes = data.notes ?? [];
  return storedNotes;
}
```

The client side consists of 2 simple routes, `index` and `notes` and i have defined 2 `NavLink` components for navigation:

```
import { NavLink } from '@remix-run/react';
...
<NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/notes">Notes</NavLink>
```

In the `notes` route, i have the following `loader` function defined which makes a call to my simulated API method:

```
import { getStoredNotes } from '~/api/notes';
...
export const loader:LoaderFunction = async () => {
  try {
    const notes = await getStoredNotes();
    return json(notes);

  } catch (error) {
    return json({ errorMessage: 'Failed to retrieve stored notes.', errorDetails: error }, { status: 400 });
  }
}
```

In the `notes` main component function i receive that data using the `useLoaderData` hook and attempt to print the returned JSON data to the console:

```
export default function NotesView() {

  const notes = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

  console.log(notes);

  return (
    <main>
      <NoteList notes={notes as Note[] || []} />
    </main>
  )
}
```

**When i run an `npm run build` and subsequently `npm run serve` everything is working correctly:**

Initial page load receives the data successfully and prints the value to the console as JSON.

```
{"notes":[{"title":"my title","content":"my note","id":"2024-03-28T05:22:52.875Z"}]}
```

Subsequent navigation client side between the `index` and `notes` routes via the `NavLink` components is also working correctly such that i see the same data print to the console.

**The problem arises when i run in development mode via `npm run dev` as follows:**

The initial page load coming from the server does load correctly and prints the JSON to the console as expected, however:

*Subsequent navigation client side* between the `index` and `notes` routes using the `NavLink` components does not print the JSON data to the console. Instead, i am seeing a JavaScript object declaration print to the console quite literally just like this:

```
export const notes = [
    {
        title: "my title",
        content: "my note",
        id: "2024-03-28T05:22:52.875Z"
    }
];
```

Is this expected behavior when running in `dev` mode?
What can i do to troubleshoot this issue?